# Batch: start application doesn't show a GUI

Tags: shell, autoit, commandlink, batch-file

I try to launch a self written autoit application called "KeyShortcuts.exe" **using a batch** called "*launchMacros.bat*". This applications provides keyboard shortcuts for various things and includes a GUI which shows me the available shortcuts.

launchMacros.bat:

```
start "MyMacros" "M:\applications\AutoIt\KeyShortcuts.exe"
```

The application does start and I'm able to **use every shortcut** but I'm **not able to see the GUI**.

If I start the application **direct** (double click on KeyShortcuts.exe) **everythings works fine**.

I also tryed starting the application using runas:

```
runas /user:REQUIREDUSERNAME /savecred "M:\applications\AutoIt\KeyShortcuts.exe"
```

Same problem here. Even right click -> "Run as administrator" doesnt worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should clarify that START is from AutoIt not from Windows batch, since they're different things (Perhaps mention AutoIt in your title). The answers that are being posted assume the latter because of this ambiguity.

Comment: Okay, there's some detail missing. I'm not sure what, perhaps some clarification on what "MyMacros" is in your script and what your KeyShortcuts.exe application actually does. If you can provide a simplified version of it here to share it will help us research your problem better.

Comment: @BicycleDude `"MyMacros"` is the title parameter for the `START` command.

Comment: Because you're using AutoIt. Have you tried an AutoIt script that invokes your AutoIt KeyShortcuts.exe applciation?

Comment: Did you compile the script with a console output? Try it, it probably helps you out while starting it from a cmd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your batch file is in a different directory than `KeyShortcuts.exe`, you may need to specify the starting directory using the `/D` parameter for `START`.

Like this:

```
START "MyMacros" /D "M:\applications\AutoIt" "M:\applications\AutoIt\KeyShortcuts.exe"
```

Comment: This is a good advice, I will check that on monday (when I am back at work).

Comment: Yeah, This is it. I am using relative sources for some GUI pictures in my application. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Every batch file launched from Windows GUI create a new console window, run the batch file, then close. If you need this to be different, there's several ways:

1. Create a shortcut to CMD /K YOURBATCHFILE.BAT
2. Add a pause to your BAT file

Here's a demonstration of method 1:

1. New > Shortcut
2. Type the location of the item: C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE
3. Type the name for this shortcut: InsertYourNameHere
4. Click Finish
5. Right click on your Shortcut and go properties
6. Change Target to: C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE /K "InsertYourBatchFileName.BAT"
7. Click OK

Done, now you have a shortcut that opens a new console window and leaves it open whilst ir runs your batch file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still can't see the Keyboard image.

Comment: @jisaak have you tried using my "CMD.EXE /K" in your BATCH file instead of using START / RUNAS ?